# Computing $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin x}dx$

Tags: integration, proof-verification

**Problem** Evaluate the following integral
$$\int_0^{2*\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin x}dx$$

**Attempted solution**

Note that 
\begin{align*}
 & \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin x}dx\\
= & \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin x}dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin x}dx\\
= & \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\left(\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin\left(x-\pi\right)}d\left(x-\pi\right)\\
= & \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\left(\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin x}dx\\
= & \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\left(\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\left(\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}}dx\\
= & \int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|dx\\
= & \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\sin\frac{x}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}dx\\
= & \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2\cos\frac{x}{2}dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\sin\frac{x}{2}dx\\
= & \left.4\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\left.4\cos\frac{x}{2}\right|_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}=\boxed{4\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align*}

**Question** I don't know if I solved this integral in the best way possible. I really appreciate if someone can offer some alternative solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A formula for $\sin x+\sin y$ may help:

$$1+\sin x = \sin\frac{\pi}{2}+\sin x = 2\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2$$

and now it should be easier

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply and divide by $\sqrt{1-\sin x}$, the integrand becomes
$$
\frac{|\cos x|}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}.
$$
Now, you can split the integrand according to the sign of the cosine, and use the subtitution $u=1-\sin x$.